# Is there a different term than percentage when wanting to show frequency of apperance?

Tags: probability, arithmetic, intuition, average, percentages

I have a rather basic question about the implication of using percentages in presenting things.

Example:
Assume we have a box with $500$ balls of which $50$ of them are red and the rest are all white.
If I start removing balls from the box in e.g. quantities of $10$ at a time or $100$ at a time, I can have the case that I keep removing white balls till I get to the last $50$.
Then I will be removing these last $50$ red balls and I would know that there are $50$ red balls in the box.

Now we could say that $10$% of the balls contained in the box are red but in reality I would not encounter $10$ red balls for every $100$ I remove. So do we use a different expression than percentage to show the difference between these cases?

Comment: Not following.  Of course, if you are removing the balls uniformly at random (so each ball left in the box is equally likely to be drawn on any turn) then the percent of the drawn balls is a random variable, which must go to $10\%$ at the end.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @lulu: I understand what you are saying. I am trying to associate it with the way we would use it in everyday expectations. E.g. if we say to someone that $10$% of the people in a neighbourhood speak French they might be surprised if they did not encounter anyone in the entire neighbourhood except the last $10$ speaking French e.g. the neighbourhood is ~$110$. So I was wondering if there is a different term to show the $1$ for every $10$ or $10$ for every $100$ than saying $10$%. I hope this is clear?

Comment: But, as you are aware, that's a random variable.  It's still a percentage, but it's numerical value depends on the sample.

Comment: If you like, you can distinguish between the *population percentage* and the *sample percentage*.  In your example, the population percentage is $10\%$, but of course the sample percentage could be anything.  For large samples you expect them to be close, but the actual number will still be uncertain.